# React: Render a single quote from json file

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm new to react and was wondering what is the "right" way to render a quote from json file to page when the component mounts.

I tried with this, but sometimes it pulls all the quotes and renders them all on the page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Quotes from '../utils/quotes';

class Home extends Component {

    getRandomQuote () {
      let keys = Object.keys(Quotes)
      return Quotes[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="PageContainer">
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <div id="quotes">Here is a quote for you:<p id="quote_text">{this.getRandomQuote()}</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is a short part to demonstrate the content of JSON file:

```
[
  "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being. - Kevin Kruse",
  "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve. - Napoleon Hill",
  "Strive not to be a success, but rather to be of value. - Albert Einstein"
]
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the JSON in `../utils/quotes`?

Comment: What's the structure of quote json? is it a string array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content that you pasted is an `array`, so you don't need to use `Object.keys` on that. Directly generate a random index by using `Math.random()` and return the result.

Write the function like this:

```
getRandomQuote() {
  return Quotes[(Quotes.length * Math.random()) << 0];
}
```

Check the working snippet:

```js
let Quotes = ["Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being. - Kevin Kruse",
    "Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve. - Napoleon Hill",
    "Strive not to be a success, but rather to be of value. - Albert Einstein"
]

let i = Quotes.length;

function getRandomQuote() {
    return Quotes[(Quotes.length * Math.random()) << 0];
}

while(i--)
   console.log(getRandomQuote());
```

Comment: Hmm. This return always the first quote. When I try console.log(Quotes.length) it returns "undefined"

Comment: check the working snippet, it's giving the proper result with different quotes.

Comment: This works when u create the array @ the start of the file, but cant get length when importing as variable like I have.

Comment: @JackM. Just use `import Quotes from '../utils/quotes';`. You might don't need * because it's just a JSON file

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara correct, i think thats the issue, Jack remove the * and try.

Comment: Oh yes that was the case ^^. Thanks!